# 0x00007FF9E2DC4A30 (msvcr120.dll) unhandled exception: request a serious program exit

Tags: c++, machine-learning, computer-vision, caffe

Recently, I'm trying to modify the classification.cpp that given by the official website of caffe so that I can use my  trained_models with C++. Although I comples it successfully, an unhandled excption occurs. How can I solve this?

Here is the partial code that I have modified (the definition of variates and functions are not changed):

```
int WinMain(int argc, char** argv) {
    clock_t start_time1, end_time1, start_time2, end_time2; 
    string model_file = "D:\\mySoftware\\caffe-windows\\examples\\mnist\\lenet.prototxt";
    string trained_file = "D:\\mySoftware\\caffe-windows\\examples\\mnist\\model1\\lenet_train_test.prototxt_iter_10000.caffemodel";
    string mean_file = "D:\\mySoftware\\caffe-windows\\examples\\mnist\mean_file\\mean.binaryproto";
    string label_file = "D:\\mySoftware\\caffe-windows\\examples\\mnist\\label.txt";

    string img_file = "D:\\mySoftware\\caffe-windows\\examples\\mnist\\data1\\my_10_images\\0.png";

    cv::Mat img = cv::imread(img_file);
    CHECK(!img.empty()) << "Unable to decode image " << img;

    start_time1 = clock();
    Classifier classifier(model_file, trained_file, mean_file, label_file);
    end_time1 = clock();
    double seconds1 = (double)(end_time1 - start_time1) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    std::cout << "init time=" << seconds1 << "s" << std::endl;

    start_time2 = clock();
    std::vector<Prediction> predictions = classifier.Classify(img);
    end_time2 = clock();
    double seconds2 = (double)(end_time2 - start_time2) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    std::cout << "classify time=" << seconds2 << "s" << std::endl;

    /* Print the top N predictions. */
    for (size_t i = 0; i < predictions.size(); ++i) {
        Prediction p = predictions[i];
        std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(4) << p.second << " - \""
            << p.first << "\"" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: `int WinMain(int argc, char** argv)` -- When has this become the valid entry point for a Windows C++ application?  That signature is for `int main()`, not for `WinMain`.  [See this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633559%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: get.I will try it.thank you.

Comment: I have tried it ,but another question occurs: Check failed: registry.count(type) == 1 (0 vs. 1) Unknown layer type: Input (known types: )@ PaulMcKenzie

Comment: it has been solved,thank you very much.